# Laravel get middleware for current route

Tags: laravel

How do you retrieve the middlewares for the current route?

I'm trying to set the exception handler to work differently based on if you're within a particular part of the website by checking if a middleware has been added to the route.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

//use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Abrigham\LaravelEmailExceptions\Exceptions\EmailHandler as ExceptionHandler;

use Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\InvalidSignatureException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Throwable;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * @param  \Throwable  $exception
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function report(Throwable $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Throwable  $exception
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     *
     * @throws \Throwable
     */
    public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
    {
        switch(true) {
            case $exception instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException:
                // Redirect back if form invalid
                return redirect()
                    ->back()
                    ->withInput($request->except($this->dontFlash))
                    ->withErrors('The form has expired due to inactivity. Please try again');

                break;
            case $exception instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException:
                // Redirect back with message if model not found error
                $redirect = app('redirect');

                // Check for different url to prevent redirect loop
                if (request()->fullUrl() === $redirect->back()->getTargetUrl()){
                    
                    // $currentRouteMiddleware = request()->route()->controllerMiddleware() returns empty array
                    // $currentRouteMiddleware = Route::current()->router->getMiddleware(); router is private

                    $response = $redirect->to(isset($currentRouteMiddleware['admin.user']) ? '/admin' : '/');
                } else {
                    $response = $redirect->back();
                }

                return $response
                    ->withInput($request->except($this->dontFlash))
                    ->withErrors('That page could not be found. Please try again or report the broken link: ' . $request->getRequestUri());

                break;
        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

If I dump the current route inside the router it shows the middleware array that I need to check against: `dd(Route::current())` but there doesn't appear to be a way of accessing the current router e.g: `$currentRouteMiddleware = Route::current()->router->getMiddleware();`

[image: route dump]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a couple options based on what you're looking for.

If you want all the middleware aliases assigned to the route, you can use:

```
Route::current()->gatherMiddleware();
```

This does not expand assigned middleware groups, so the result from this might look something like:

```
[
    'web',
    'admin.user'
]
```

If you want all of the middleware classes assigned to the route, you can use:

```
Route::gatherRouteMiddleware(Route::current());
```

This will give you the classes, but it will not have the associated aliases or groups for the classes. The result from this might look like:

```
[
    "App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies",
    "Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse",
    "Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession",
    "Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession",
    "App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken",
    "Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings",
    "TCG\Voyager\Http\Middleware\VoyagerAdminMiddleware"
]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Route::getMiddleware()` in the Handler is simply a list of `\App\Http\Kernel::$routeMiddleware`.

```
dd(Route::getMiddleware());

array:7 [▼
  "auth" => "App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate"
  "auth.basic" => "Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth"
  "guest" => "App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated"
  "admin" => "App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware"
  // ...
]
```

It is recommended to declare a constant (or global variable) and check whether the corresponding constant is declared in the Handler to check whether `AdminMiddleware` has passed.

```
// app/Http/Middleware/AdminMiddleware.php

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // if ... return ...

        define('__APP_IS_ADMIN', true);

        return $next($request);
    }
```

```
// app/Exceptions/Handler.php

    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        // ...

        $response = $redirect->to(defined('__APP_IS_ADMIN') ? '/admin' : '/');
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
request()->route()->controllerMiddleware();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this always returns empty array. I'm doing this inside the exception handler but even inside the controller it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

List middlewares applied in the current route inside App\Exceptions\Handler. Using in unauthenticated method.

```
/**
 * Convert an authentication exception into a response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException  $exception
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    return $request->expectsJson()
        ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)
        : redirect()->guest(in_array('admin', $request->route()->middleware(), true) ? route('admin.login') : route('login'));
}
```

I used this to get the "admin" middleware and redirect the user to the correct login page.